# On CPU start-up cause Start-up my Device Connected on ParallelPort?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, parallel-port

I am using `ParallelPort` to do communicate with One **Electric Device.**

My Task on `ParallelPort` is to just **start and stop device.**
For that I have write up following code:
One `static` Class `ParellelPort` which contain Method `static extern void Output(int address, int value)`.

```
public static class ParellelPort
    {
        [DllImport("inpout32.dll",EntryPoint = "Out32")]
        public static extern void Output(int address, int value);
    }
```

Using that method

I do write something on `ParallelPort` in my case **just writing 1 and 0.**

For starting and stopping Device.
i using following Code.

```
private const int PORT_ADDRESS = 0x0378;
int startMachine = 1;
int stopMachine = 0;

ParellelPort.Output(PORT_ADDRESS, startMachine); //For starting Device.

ParellelPort.Output(PORT_ADDRESS, stopMachine);//For Stoping Device.
```

Now my **PROBLEM IS,**

**Whenever i am starting CPU it cause start Device automatically as CPU writing on Parallel**

**Port each time it starts.**

**So starting of CPU start my DEVICE  I need to get rid of it.**

**Is there any way to disable ParallelPort or way something like this to get rid of it.**

**NOTE:**

I am using **PIN-2** for **Communicate with my device.**

Each time I write **value=1** on `ParallelPort` **5 volt** is available at **PIN-2** and**(this cause starts my Device)**

When write **value=0** on on `ParallelPort` **0 volt** is available at **PIN-2 (this cause stops my Device)**.

And whenever CPU start  **5 volt** is available on each **DataPort Pin** from **PIN-2 to PIN-9(this cause starts my Device on CPU starts-up).**

[image]

Thanks.....

Comment: electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: i have got one logical solution over [here][1] 


  [1]: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17515/on-cpu-start-up-cause-start-up-my-device-connected-on-parallelport/17518#17518

Answer (score 2):

The design of the computer hardware causes reset signals to be sent to most periphials at POST time, there's nothing you can do in software to prevent this.  All you can do is design the device to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks for answering..but i am thinking on Make on app which start each time CPU start and write `Value=0` at `ParallelPort` so it will stops my Device.

Comment: @Aryan SuryaWansi - You can't do that.  The Periphial Reset occurs before any operating system has loaded.  As such, you can't run any app because no software is yet running.

Comment: but my device remain start after OS have been loaded. so after Loading of OS i can start my app and writ value=0 to parallelport so i can stops my device.......i think this should work.......isn't it??

Comment: @Aryan SuryaWansi - I thought you wanted to prevent the device from starting on reset.  If you're ok with just turning it off when the computer boots, then yes.. you can write a small app that would load at startup to turn it off.  Seems hackish, but if that works for you.